# How to Add or Repair kube-dns in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-dns, amazon-eks

I'm running 1.10.13 on EKS on two clusters.  I'm aware this will soon be obsolete for coredns on 1.11+.

One of our clusters has a functioning kube-dns deployment.
The other cluster does not have kube-dns objects running.

I've pulled kube-dns serviceAccount, clusterRole, clusterRoleBinding, deployment, and service manifests from here using `kubectl get <k8s object> --export`.

Now I plan on applying those files to a different cluster.

However, I still see a kube-dns secret and I'm not sure how that is created or where I can get it.

This all seems pretty roundabout.  What is the proper way of installing or repairing kube-dns on an EKS cluster?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the secret is usually part of the ServiceAccount, you'd still need to delete if it's there.

To create kube-dns you can try applying the official manifest:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-the-hard-way/kube-dns.yaml`
```

Like you mentioned, you should consider moving to coredns as soon as possible.

Comment: That looks Google specific.  ClusterIP is hardcoded and images are on gcr.io.  The serviceAccount section doesn't specifically mention a secret.

Comment: It is but you can remove the clusterIP from the definition